# unordered_map reports "vector subscript out of range" assertion when using [] operator

Tags: c++, vector, std, unordered-map

This is an odd one. I have a map of maps of a struct. Attempting to insert an element will give me a static assertion in std::vector that reads "vector subscript out of range"

Here is what my definition looks like:

```
class A {
  struct tag_info_t {
    uint8_t x, y, z;
  }
  using tag_info_map = std::unordered_map<uint16_T, tag_info_t>;
  std::unordered_map<uint16_t, tag_info_map> id_to_poller_to_info_map;

  void foo(uint16_t, uint16_t, tag_info&);
}
```

I have a loop in a thread doing insertions like this:

```
void A::foo(uint16_t tag, uint16_t poller, tag_info& info ) {
  id_to_poller_to_info_map[tag][poller] = info;
}
```

Sometimes (and not every time) I'll hit this assertion at this point! I'd love some information pointing to why this might be happening. It's really frustrating. I'm using MSVC140 (VS2015). Thanks!

Comment: Please provide a [MCVE].

Comment: I figured out my issue while trying to reproduce. It turns out I forgot to name my lock_guards, so the constructor would get called but they'd get thrown away instantly. My threads would compete with each other and clobber the internals of the maps.

Comment: @Michael Heh, I've done that plenty of times, sadly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you mention threads and the fact that it only happens sometimes hints that this is a concurrency issue. The unordered_map is not thread-safe, you must not modify the same instance from multiple threads at the same time.
Reading from it from multiple threads is fine.

As mentioned before, try to provide a complete example so we can understand what is happening better.

Comment: This answer is the most accurate